# Why map's elements don't need copy or move constructors but vector's do?

Tags: c++, c++11, dictionary, vector, containers

I have this class:

```
class Object {
public:
    Object();
    Object(const Object&) = delete;
    Object& operator=(const Object&) = delete;
    ~Object();
};
```

- The default copy constructor & assign operator is deleted,
- no move constr./assign op. declared,
- and there is also no implicit move constr./assign op. because there is a destructor declared.

When I try to store it in a `std::vector`:

```
std::vector<Object> objects;
objects.emplace_back();
```

**It gives a compile error because Object doesn't have a copy constructor/move c./etc.**

- (it is needed because on resizing the objects have to be copied/moved to the new container)

But when I try to store it in an `std::map`:

```
std::map<int, Object> objects;
objects.emplace(std::piecewise_construct,
    std::make_tuple(1),
    std::make_tuple()
);
```

**It works perfectly. Why?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`std::map` is a node based container (a [red-black tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Red%E2%80%93black_tree), for example). The elements are stored in internal node structures that the map can move around internally. To reposition an element, it just need to update some pointers, it doesn't need to move the element itself.

`std::vector` stores the elements in a contiguous buffer. Every time the buffer is reallocated (which can be often enough), the elements themselves need to be moved. So it must be possible to so.